# How to find duplicated vaules in Tableau

Tags: python, duplicates, tableau-api

I need to create a new column that advises if a customer is new or recurrent.

To do so I want to check, for each unique value in phone, if there is one or more date associated in the Date columns.

```
 Phone   Date
0    a   1
1    a   1
2    a   2
3    b   2
4    b   2
5    c   3
6    c   2
7    c   1
```

New users are those for whom there is only one unique (Phone, Date) couple with the same phone. The result that I want looks like:

```
Phone   Date    User_type
0   a   1   recurrent
1   a   1   recurrent
2   a   2   recurrent
3   b   2   new
4   b   2   new
5   c   3   recurrent
6   c   2   recurrent
7   c   1   recurrent
```

I manage to do it in few lines of code with python but my boss want insist that I do it in Tableau.

I know I need to use a calculated field but that's it.

If it can help, here is my python code that does the same:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for item in set(data.Phone):
    if len(set(data[data.Phone == item]['Date'])) == 1:
        data.loc[data.Phone == item, 'type_user'] = 'new'
    elif len(set(data[tata.Phone == item]['Date'])) > 1:
        data.loc[data.Phone == item, 'type_user'] = 'recurrent'
    else:
        data.loc[data.Phone == item, 'type_user'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LOD to do that, the below will give you how many records are duplicated

```
{Fixed [Phone],[Date]: SUM([Number of Records])}
```

If you want a text, do:

```
IF {Fixed [Phone],[Date]: SUM([Number of Records])} > 1 THEN 'recurrent' ELSE 'new' END
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for you reply! It didn't exactly solved my problem but it definitely helped me finding the solution.

The solution:

I first got, for a given phone, the number of distinct Date

```
{Fixed [Phone] : COUNT([Date])}
```

Then I created my categorical (dimension) variable

```
if {Fixed [Phone] : COUNT([Date])} > 1 THEN 'recurrent' ELSE 'new' END
```

The result (phone numbers are hidden for data privacy reasons):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnPrj.png)

Comment: On your answer you are fixing the phone and counting the dates for that phone. It will not take distinct if you use count but countd should be used instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must admit that I struggle a bit to understand what certains functions do in Tableau